# Can gexf (gephi) file be added into into a webpage?

Tags: graph, gephi

I created a GEXF file to run it in Gephi and generate graphs. Now i want to export these graphs into a html page i have created. Is there any possible way i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can embedded a GEXF graph in a HTML page using a javascript graph drawing library such as [SigmaJS](http://sigmajs.org/).

There is a builtin example where a GEXF graph is loaded [here](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/examples/load-external-gexf.html).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. I have heard about SigmaJS before. When i researched on it, i was asked to install a plugin , ' sigma.parseGexf.js ' . But i have no idea how to install it. It is a java script but i cant execute is as well. If its okay, can you explain to be how to use SigmaJS to export gephi graph into html. , step by step ?